# QTcpServer- QTcpSocket acknowledgement question

Tags: qt, qt4, network-programming, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

-->I am writing a program using QTcpSocket,QTcpServer. Do I need to add some code(i.e. an acknowledgement procedure) to guarantee that the packets are delivered?
   If this is the case, I could not find anything like that on the net, therefore would like to see some examples,please.

-->Or in the QT library somewhere, these are already covered so that I do not need anything like that?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT:
Now, I am asking how to use headers with the chunks of QDataStream I added below. I want each and every chunk to have headers telling information.So that I can keep track of which parts are written, which are missing.. Please have a look at below.

```
///RECEIVER SIDE

QDataStream in(socket);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

QByteArray next;
next=socket->readAll(); 

QFile output("c:\\some\\output.txt");
output.open(QIODevice::Append);
output.write(next);
output.close();


///SENDER SIDE
QByteArray block;
QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

QFile file(path);
if(file.exists()){
         file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);    
}

QByteArray data; 
data=file.readAll();
block.append(data);

out << (quint64)0;
out.device()->seek(0);
if(!socket->waitForBytesWritten()){
    qDebug()<<"writing";
 socket->write(block);
 socket->flush();
}


file.close();
qDebug()<<"data: size"<<file.size();
socket->disconnectFromHost();
```

Comment: For me, I added code in both server and client sides. The server responses acknowledgement when it gets something and the clients can know the acknowledgement.

Comment: For instance, I am sending huge amount of data by dividing that into smaller chunks. Do I need to trigger "ACK" mechanism for each and every one of these chunk deliveries or should I do that when the whole package is sent.

Answer (score 2):

TCP guarantees ordered delivery. Once you submit data to TCP socket the stack will try to send as much as it can. Stack uses internal acknowledgement messages to guarantee delivery.

So you don't need to send acknowledgements however, it is a good idea to implement a header for your packets so that receiving side can properly merge small packets back into a huge file.

Comment: I thought about that too, however I cannot reach those chunks I've been talking about because I am using QDataStream. Is there a way of reaching those of the stream and put headers in front of them?

Comment: You can send more than one buffer to a QDataStream. First send you header, then the rest. First word would typically be the size of the header and/or protocol version number.